# how can I load a NPAPI plugin In safari

Tags: plugins, installation

To install the plugin, just copy it into one of these two locations:

/Library/Internet Plugins/
~/Library/Internet Plugins/

but how can I auto install plugin when i open a web page,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really "how can I force a user to automatically download and execute arbitrary binary code when they open a web page". For obvious reasons, the answer is "you can't".

If you want users to download and install a plugin you're going to have to have a download link, and instructions on how to install it once it's downloaded. Then *the user* will have to install it.

Comment: I'm confused how safari web page found lack of Plugins and download link, install it? have a example?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you're asking how to tell via JS if a given plugin is installed, you should post a new question (after checking that it's not a duplicate; I'd be surprised if nobody has asked that before).